# Deciding whether to cast or Project when meters needed for ST_Distance?

Tags: coordinate-system, srid, st-distance

I have a database and I am using geoms to build polygons around points.

I need to do st_distance, st_area, st_overlaps, st_union, and st_instersects. also using st_x and st_y and st_project, so pretty sure i have to use geometry data type for these operations.

My issue is that I need meters, not degrees to get st_distance between points, and and st_area of polygons.

Should i do a cast with the :: operator to convert to geography or should i project?

Also, how do I choose which srid to pick?

My input could be anywhere in the US (including AL, HI).

Comment: agreeing with @robinloche; if you are constructing polygons based on distance and bearing, don't project, as 'ST_Project` naturally requires the input to be *geography*. use EPSG:4326 (*geometry*) and cast to *geography* for `ST_Distance`, `ST_Area` and `ST_Project`. btw., *use_spheroid* is the default and yields best precision.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in 4326, I'm pretty sure you can just cast in ::geography (don't forget to set the boolean use_spheroid at the end of ST_Distance and ST_Area). The result of these functions, if you use a geography type, will be in meters.

If you want computation to be faster, you can either put use_spheroid to false (it will then use a sphere approximation) or to project it, like you said. I don't know much about US projection, but it's not that north so a good 3857 (web mercator) should be enough if a little approximation doesn't scare you (commonly used, depends of your precision needs: horizontal scale factor: 1/cos(latitude): [What's the accuracy of Web Mercator EPSG:3857?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184648/whats-the-accuracy-of-web-mercator-epsg3857) )

Comment: just a note, though: I wouldn't advice to use EPSG:3857 for *anything* involving spatial analyses, despite the fact it might have tolerable distortions at the equator. maybe and only if your data setup points a gun to your head...