# Print Layout - scale bar is correct - scale ratio not matching up

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale, printing

I have been asked to include a scale reference to my map of a property. The scale bar seems correct from a sense check but the scale is saying 1:500 which does not match. I would suggest it may be more like 1:4.5. The print layout has been matched to the canvas scale.

I've added a screenshot of both the print layout and the canvas for your info.

[image: map canvas showing 1:500 scale]

[image: print layout showing correct scale bar but incorrect scale]

Comment: Scale refers to the map in its printed form. Depending on how your page setup is and how large you defined the map item on it, this is not the same as the size on your screen: on a large screen is shown in another real-world size, whereas on a phone's screen, it's much smaller - the defined size in layout units (e.g. cm) remains the same.

Comment: Also your map is in epsg:3857 that is a really bad choice for accurate measurement (see this for more on that : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184648/whats-the-accuracy-of-web-mercator-epsg3857)